# Why is Angular 8 lazy loading causing this element to redirect and embed itself into the router outlet twice?

Tags: angular, module, routes, lazy-loading

I've recently modularized an Angular 8 app for the first time, which was easy enough, but when I started implementing lazy loading, weird things started happening with the routing. This is the main problem:

[image: Every lazy loaded element (Users, Online Orders, and Salesperson) does this]

Rather than embedding the Overview component, as well as the dashboard (navbars and all), it should open the selected component (Users, in the case of this example).

Here's my lazy loading code:

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard],
    canActivateChild: [CanActivateRoute],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'overview',
        component: OverviewComponent,
        data: { title: 'Overview', requiredRoles: [Role.SALESPERSON] }
      },
      {
        path: 'users',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./dashboard/users/users.module').then(m => m.UsersModule),
        data: { title: 'Users', requiredRoles: [Role.SALES_ADMIN] }
      },
      {
        path: 'online-orders',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./dashboard/online-orders/online-orders.module').then(
            m => m.OnlineOrdersModule
          ),
        data: {
          title: 'Online Orders',
          requiredRoles: [Role.SALES_ADMIN]
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'salesperson',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./dashboard/salesperson/salesperson.module').then(
            m => m.SalespersonModule
          ),
        data: {
          title: 'Salesperson',
          requiredRoles: [Role.SALESPERSON]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard/unauthorized',
    component: UnauthorizedComponent,
    data: { title: 'Unauthorized' }
  },
  { path: 'implicit/callback', component: OktaCallbackComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: 'dashboard/error',
    component: ErrorComponent,
    data: { title: 'Error' }
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard/overview' }
];
```

Judging by this information in the console I got using `enableTracing`, I'm guessing one of the main issues is that it's getting redirected instead of going straight to the correct component:

```
RoutesRecognized {
    id: 4, 
    url: "/dashboard/users", 
    urlAfterRedirects: "/dashboard/users/dashboard/overview/", 
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
}
```

As you can see, instead of just navigating to `/dashboard/users`, it's adding a second `/dashboard/` to the end as well as redirecting to `/overview/` on top of that.

I'm guessing it has something to do with having multiple router outlets in the app, but this worked fine before lazy loading was implemented.

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="app-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**layout.component.html**

```
<div class="app-content">
    <mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
        <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <app-top-menu></app-top-menu>
    <section>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet> //<----
    </section>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried:

- Lazy loading the Overview component (Opening the page creates an endless loop)
- Renaming one of the router outlets (Breaks the routing and throws errors in the console)

I'm a junior developer and I'm still learning how Angular apps are put together (especially with routing), so hopefully someone can help me see what I might be overlooking. I've seen similar issues to this but none where the component is getting embedded within itself like this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you have your AppComponent.html having a router-outlet and not using the app component inside your route. So the main app ends up inside that. If you inspect the html you will see the app is inside:

```
<div class="app-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

as well as inside:

```
<section>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet> //<----
    </section>
```

Unsure as to how to solve it, though. You could try one of two. Either removing the router-outlet inside your app.component.html or test this:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
 component: AppComponent,
children: [

  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [OktaAuthGuard],
    canActivateChild: [CanActivateRoute],
    children: [
```

etc. This might require some tweaking though to get it to work. But normally this is what you do, having the top level have a path '', then as a child specifying a route.

If this doesn't work, inspect your html and report back what you see in the html, that's a very useful tool to help debug if what I suspect above is not the case.